# I updated my Eclipse to Photon and advice is this a bug?

Tags: java

I am very confused and losing it, can someone tell me what is wrong with this code, so I can't see to understand why this, I am ready to be rectified on what I seem not to see. please I even tried debugging and there is an error. Help a sister here. Is this a bug ? I am working on this question and using the number line idea if it is less that zero subtract, if greater add, if equal zero count. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus/problem

Practice class:

```
public class PracticeClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr [] = {-4 ,3, -9 ,0, 4 ,1 };
        getPlusMinus(arr);



    }   

    private static void getPlusMinus(int [] arr) {
        double plus = 0.0;
        double minus = 0.0;
        double zero = 0.0;

        int n = arr.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(arr[i] > plus) {
                plus++;
            }
            if(arr[i] < minus) {
                minus++;
            }
            if(arr[i] == zero) {
                zero++;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%.6f %n",plus/n);
        System.out.printf("%.6f %n",minus/n);
        System.out.printf("%.6f %n",zero/n);

    }
```

}

prints OUTPUT:

```
    0.333333 
0.666667 
0.000000
```

yet the same code on a different file

```
public class PlusMinusFraction {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int arr [] = {-4 ,3, -9, 0, 4 ,1};

           plusMinus(arr);


    }

    private static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double plus = 0.0;
        double minus = 0.0;
        double zero = 0.0;

        int n = arr.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            if(arr[i] > 0) {
                plus++;
            }
            if(arr[i] < 0) {
                minus++;
            }
            if(arr[i] == 0) {
                zero++;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("%.6f %n", plus/n);
        System.out.printf("%.6f %n", minus/n);
        System.out.printf("%.6f %n", zero/n);


    }


}
```

Prints  OUTPUT

```
0.500000 
0.333333 
0.166667
```

Comment: They're not at all the same, as a simple [diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/Rt6SVnhH) would demonstrate.

Comment: I actually forgot to add, they all have the /n and have different output. Lol

Comment: @shmosel try running the project.

Comment: Your `if`s are still different.

Comment: Hahaha, @shmosel I see I am tired now. working on this tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is just an IDE, it merely redirects the program output to certain window.

Your programs are different, looks at the last 3 sout lines

Program 1:

```
System.out.printf("%.6f %n",plus);
System.out.printf("%.6f %n",minus);
System.out.printf("%.6f %n",zero);
```

Program 2:

```
System.out.printf("%.6f %n", plus/n);
System.out.printf("%.6f %n", minus/n);
System.out.printf("%.6f %n", zero/n);
```

Can you see the difference here? Plus there are more differences in the function itself. As suggested in comment a simple text diff would help more.

Comment: Apologies they actually have the /n on all. I forgot to add here.

Comment: There are more differences, as suggested do a simple text diff and you would figure out the changes.

Comment: can you try running it, .